# Oracle event processing. How to insert data into database?

Tags: database, oracle12c, complex-event-processing, oracle-soa

I am trying to use OEP to read messages from a JMS queue and put the messages into the database. The processor seems to be reading from database only? I am not sure about this, but all the examples I can see are SELECT CQL queries. Is there any way I can have something like a database outbound adapter to put the messages into the database as the last step? Or I should use OEP eventBean with JDBC to do this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **CQL** (Continuous Query Language) allows to continuously query events from Streams. Streams data are processed in memory, so there is not an `INSERT` clause in the CQL because there is not a database behind. You can define a database table as source for a processor and enrich your events joining Streams and Database data, but if you want to insert data into a Database you need to do it yourself using an event bean. The `Oracle Event Processing` installation includes the EclipseLink open source mapping and persistence framework to support the use of the `Java Persistence API` (`JPA`) in your applications. So in your event bean you can use `JPA` or of course `JDBC` to persist your events.